# Accessing ForeignKey field after creating entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When creating a new entity, if I try to access one of the foreign key fields immediately after creation, I'm getting an object reference exception. Here's the code -

```
        Call call = new Call()
        {
            ....
            StoreID = storeID,    //foreign key of store
            ....
        }
        db.Calls.Add(call);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ....

        // do something with store
        call.Store.Anything();
```

This throws:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Because `call.Store` is not mapped to any object

Note that the code works perfectly if I don't try to access the Store object. If I redirect the user and the call is loaded from scratch, then accessing the Store object works no problem.

As a nasty hack I tried

```
 db.Entry(call).Reload();
```

but even that didn't help

How can I make the store object immediately accessible upon creation?

---

The model:

```
[Table("CALL_LOG")]
public class Call
{
    .....

    [Column("STORE_IID"), Required]
    public int StoreID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StoreID")]
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }

    .....
 }
```

Comment: It's normal for a parent record on a child to be null if you haven't establishedthe parent yet. You have to set the Store property equal to the Store record that will be the call's parent before saving. If you have something external setting the foreign key field then reloading may do you some good. Have you checked the database to see if the StoreID on the record has been set to something other than NULL in CALL_LOG for your new record?

Comment: @JamieSee He is setting the StoreID when he creates the Call object. It will insert that but the object is just not loaded in the Context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work I believe:

```
db.Entry<Call>(call).Reference("Store").Load()
```

This will tell it to load the Store navigation property.

Comment: This works, thanks. Still seems a little bit dirty. In my opinion the object should be 100% usable as soon as you hit db.SaveChanges().

Comment: @NoPyGod I agree that if it is marked virtual then the logical think would be for it to load it when you try and access it, but the problem with that is that you are not dealing with an instance of the proxy class, you are dealing with an instance of the actual class, so lazy loading can't really work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that I see more code that makes sense. Since you are storing the ID, you need to hit the database again to inflate the object.

```
Call call = new Call()
{

    ....

    StoreID = storeID,    //foreign key of store

    ....

}

db.Calls.Add(call);

db.SaveChanges();
call = db.Calls.Single(c => c.CallId = call.CallId).Include(c => c.Store);

....

// do something with store

call.Store.Anything();
```

Comment: Yes I did try that, it has the same effect -- still not working. Which is more correct to use anyway?

Comment: No that will not work, it will have the same effect. The Store property is not being set. I updated my post to show how the StoreID field is set. The Store property should be automatically linked to the related Store object.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid hitting the database for the whole call. I got an answer above. Thanks though.

Comment: FYI, the marked answer still hits the database. Open up SQL Profiler, you will see.

Comment: But it would only hit the database for the store object and not the call+store.. I presume. I am at home now so I cannot verify.

Comment: Thats true. If you wanted just the store, you could do db.Stores.Find(call.StoreID). Or go with the marked answer DbEntityEntry.Reference. Either way, the db will be queried if the Store is not loaded into the DbContext.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right:
1. you are creating new Call-instance somehow not using db (with `call = new Call()` ?) instance before adding it with this line:

```
db.Calls.Add(call);
```

2. You get a `NullReferenceException` after trying to access the Store property.

If that's the case, adding a ctor, which will initialize Store, to Call class may help.

```
public Call()
{
 ...
    this.Store = new Store();
}
```

Comment: The Store is not a new object, it's supposed to be loaded from the database using the ForeignKey. I updated my post to show how the StoreID field is set.